# Does EKS supports kubenet or some type of virtual network to get more IP space?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-eks

My company gave us has a very small subnet size (like 30 IP addresses). By default in K8 every node gets a ton of IPs assigned to it, and every pod gets an IP, so having only 30 IPs to draw from isn't nearly enough to run a K8 cluster. I need hundreds, specifically around 400 or more to be able so stand up this cluster. I never used EKS and this is what we will be using. After some research I saw that that AKS in Azure can do virtual networks (so you can have all the IPs you need) with kubenet, so even with a small subnet Kubernetes can still function. This doc explains it pretty well from Azure side https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-kubenet.

I am still digging if EKS uses kubenet, and haven't found anything yet. I would appreciate any feedback for a virtual server or plugin I can use in EKS to get more IP space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having trouble finding information on EKS utilizing kubenet because kubenet has a significant limitation in AWS that is not present in Azure. EKS utilizing kubenet is limited to a theoretical limit of 50 cluster nodes because kubenet relies on the VPC routing table for access to other EKS nodes. Because AWS limits the number of routes on a VPC routing table to 50, the number of EKS nodes is theoretically 50 (Less if you consider default route for internet traffic or routes to other EC2 instances)

In AKS (Azure) the UDR limit for a subnet is 250 (254 - 4 reserved by Azure).

EKS deploys with the CNI plugin enabled by default. You can get around the small subnet limitation by enabling CNI with custom networking which allows you to have the same type of IP Masquerade that you get with kubenet (i.E a separate internal kubernetes network for pods that is NAT'd to the EKS EC2 Nodes interface).

Here is a good description:
https://medium.com/elotl-blog/kubernetes-networking-on-aws-part-i-99012e938a40